# Azure CosmosDB - compound indexes - concept of foreseeing sorts by user inputs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am currently - who guessed it - facing a conceptional missunderstanding, how can you provide an API service with a sort feature, using mongoose@4 and CosmosDB@MongoAPI4.0. The API service is consumed by users/frontend and third-party API services in a cloud environment.

As I know, whenever you sort multiple fields, CosmosDB requires a compound index. I read the past 2 days Microsoft Azure Cosmosdb documentation from front to back about this topic.

As you see, the frontend supports a multiple choice between specified columns, namely properties of the underlying schema translated for user convenience.

**How do You support such a simple requirement with CosmosDB? Do I add every, single, combination out of these for about 10 collections in my DB??** I highly doubt this concept in my head, so I ask you, lovly SO for help.

[image: Example Frontend with function "sort"]

Answer (score 0):

Short anwser is yes. You will need to create an index for each combination of all your properties to make such a query possible on the database side.

I think the reason for that is because Cosmos snips your requests in small bits that are stateless of nature. So if you order on anything that is not indexed it would have to recalculate the order of all elements for every past request in a series of requests for one query.

Another possibility would be for you to order the results on the client side. Or even create a mixture where a selection of properties are sorted on the database side and the rest client sided.